# LDAP : ldapsearch segfault error

Tags: segmentation-fault, certificate, openldap, starttls

I am confronted with a problem using openLDAP and ldapsearch. The server is RHEL6.1 and the configuration of ldap is normally correct, many other servers with the same LDAP configuration work well. When I run `ldapsearch -x -ZZ` command, I got the following error : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Here is the last lines from `ldapsearch -x -ZZ -d -1` :

```
ldap_msgfree
TLS: certdb config: configDir='/etc/openldap/cacerts' tokenDescription='ldap(0)' certPrefix='' keyPrefix='' flags=readOnly
TLS: cannot open certdb '/etc/openldap/cacerts', error -8192:Unknown code ___f 0
TLS: loaded CA certificate file /etc/openldap/cacerts/ca.crt.
TLS: skipping 'ca.crt' - filename does not have expected format (certificate hash with numeric suffix)
TLS: skipping 'servad01' - filename does not have expected format (certificate hash with numeric suffix)
TLS: loaded CA certificate file /etc/openldap/cacerts/a50bd25e.0 from CA certificate directory /etc/openldap/cacerts.
TLS: error: the certificate '/etc/openldap/cacerts/servad01/servad01.crt' could not be found in the database - error -8187:Unknown code ___f 5.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The file `servad01.crt` exists :

```
[root openldap]# cat 
/etc/openldap/cacerts/servad01/servad01.crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

[...]

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little late but the problem was solved by installing `nslcd`